# How can I write an IF condition for my decision variable for Mixed Integer Linear Programming (MILP) using PuLP GLPK on Python?

Tags: python, pulp, glpk

I am trying to solve an optimization problem using mixed integer linear programming on PuLP with GLPK solver on Python. So far I have been successful solving basic optimization problems with constraints, such as:

```
prob = LpProblem("MILP", LpMinimize)
x1 = LpVariable("x1",lowBound=0, cat = 'Binary')
x2 = LpVariable("x2", cat = 'Continuous')
prob += 4*x1 + x2, "Objective Function"
prob += x2 - 4*x1 <= 0
prob += x2 - 2*x1 >= 0
status = prob.solve()
LpStatus[status]
value(x1), value(x2), value(prob.objective)
```

This gives an optimum result where x1 = 1.0, x2 = 3.0 and Objective Function = 7.0

What I'm trying to figure out is how can I solve an optimization problem with an **if** condition in, for example, the following constraint:

```
x1 > 0 IF x2 > 2
```

or something like:

```
x1 > 0 IF x2 == 3
```

Bascially, how can I integrate an if conditional statement into the MILP constraints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The search term you are looking for is "indicator variable", or "big-M constraint".

As far as I know PULP doesn't directly support indicator variables, so a big-M constraint is the way to go.

***A Simple Example***:
`x1 <= 0 IF x2 > 2`

```
from pulp import *

prob = LpProblem("MILP", LpMaximize)
x1 = LpVariable("x1", lowBound=0, upBound=10, cat = 'Continuous')
x2 = LpVariable("x2", lowBound=0, upBound=10, cat = 'Continuous')

prob += 0.5*x1 + x2, "Objective Function"

b1 = LpVariable("b1", cat='Binary')

M1 = 1e6
prob += b1 >= (x1 - 2)/M1

M2 = 1e3
prob += x2 <= M2*(1 - b1)

status = prob.solve()
print(LpStatus[status])
print(x1.varValue, x2.varValue, b1.varValue, pulp.value(prob.objective))
```

We want a constraint `x1 <= 0` to exist when `x2 > 2`. When `x2 <= 2` no such constraint exists (`x1` can be either positive or negative).

First we create a binary variable:

```
b1 = LpVariable("b1", cat='Binary')
```

Choose this to represent the condition `x2 > 2`. The easiest way to achieve this adding a constraint:

```
M1 = 1e6
prob += b1 >= (x2 - 2)/M1
```

Here `M1` is the big-M value. It needs to be chosen such that for the largest possible value of `x2` the expression `(x2-2)/M` is `<=1`. It should be as small as possible to avoid numerical/scaling issues. Here a value of 10 would work (`x2` has upper bound of 10).

To understand how this contraint works, think of the cases, for x2<=2 the right-hand-side is at-most 0, and so has no effect (lower bound of a binary variable already set to 0). However if `x2>2` the right hand side will force `b1` to be more than 0 - and as a binary variable it will be forced to be 1.

Finally, we need to build the required constraint:

```
M2 = 1e3
prob += x1 <= M2*(b1 - 1)
```

Again to understand how this constraint works, consider the cases, if b1 is true (`1`) the constraint is active and becomes: `x1 <= 0`. If b1 is false ('0') the constraint becomes `x1 <= M2`, provided `M2` is large enough this will have no effect (here it could be as small as 10 as `x1` already has an upper bound of 10.

In the full code above if you vary the coefficient of `x1` in the objective function you should notice that `b1` is activated/de-activated and the additional constraint applied to `x1` as expected.